# Can anybody please undelete my deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, moderators, deleted-questions

There was a question which has been deleted by a moderator and there are some that I deleted, and I was thinking to undelete all of them so that this time, I can improve my posts including the one that had been deleted by a moderator in a proper manner, because now I got a plan how to improve in a proper manner. So, please can you undelete all of them? I want my posts on Islam Stack Exchange to be undelete all of them, only for one time. “Because”, I don’t have enough reputations to undelete all of them.

Comment: Fix first, undelete later. Deleted posts should not be undeleted until the problems that lead to their deletion have been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you deleted your own question, you can [undelete it yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/132874).

If the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/132874) deleted your question, the community didn't want it and nobody cared enough to keep it around; undeleting it *before* fixing any of its problems is just a waste of everyone's time.

If the question was deleted by votes, the community obviously *wanted* it gone; if you want us to go against an established community decision, you should at least *try* to make a good case for doing so.

If a diamond moderator deleted your question, they probably had a very good reason for doing so, and it's unlikely to be undeleted without addressing that *first*.

In any case, just a blanket request to undelete all everything is not gonna accomplish anything; if you have a *particular* post that you think warrants undeletion, you're better off making that case individually in its own meta post.

Comment: Yeah, I know the reason. And the reason is that I had too many grammatical and punctuation mistakes and I did like 70 edits. And I want second chance to fix in a proper manner. “Because” I really got a plan how to do it.

Comment: But all of my questions except one, have been deleted because I wanted and now I woke up that I did a mistake

Comment: And that “except one” has been deleted by a moderator.